LM317 current limiting - reference cuircuit datasheet - function of diodes in adjust?
I'm looking into using an LM317 as current limiter to serve as a simple constant current charger for 3S lithium 18650 cells.
Found following posts as inspiration:

what-use-are-the-transistors-in-this-lm317-based-power-supply-circuit
smartest-way-to-use-current-limit-using-lm317
the datasheet

I don't really need adjusting to 0 current (for which a negative supply voltage is needed according to the datasheet).
But it seems nice to adjust the current to experiment,
so I replaced the depletion mode JFET with a constant current circuit based on a transistor and without a negative supply voltage.
I simulated the result with CircuitJS Desktop,
the 3 cell series battery pack (3S) with BMS (the BMS should take care of over-voltage) is "approximated" with a resistor (100 Ohm).
While playing around with this I removed the 2 diodes (D1 & D2 - see pictures below) used across the pot-meter (i.e. opened the switch in the simulation).
I saw that these diodes hardly play a role.
Even better, when they are not there (open switch), then I can regulate more deep (towards 0 current) then when they are there.
And from the simulation I see no averse effects.
3 screenshots from the simulation:
Minimum current with the diodes over the pot-meter.

Minimum current with "no diodes" over the pot-meter.

Maximum current: with or without diodes over the pot-meter makes no difference.

So what what is the function of these diodes D1 and D2, and/or do they only serve a purpose in the original reference circuit as mentioned in the datasheet (with the JFET and negative supply voltage)?


I don't really need adjusting to 0 current


So what what is the function of these diodes D1 and D2, and/or do they only serve a purpose in the original reference circuit as mentioned in the datasheet (with the JFET and negative supply voltage)?

Here is the original circuit in the LM317 datasheet.

The purpose in the original reference circuit is to ensure that regardless of the \$I_{DSS}\$ of the JFET, the voltage across the ends of the potentiometer will be approximately 1.2 V, allowing the voltage between the output and adjust pins of the LM317 to be approximately 1.2 V even when there is negligible voltage drop across \$R_{SC}\$ because there is negligible output current.
The 2N3822 has an \$I_{DSS}\$ range of 2 mA to 10 mA. Without the diodes present, the this corresponds to a range for a voltage across the potentiometer ends of 2 to 10 V. With the diodes present, the range is reduced to, say 1.2 V to 1.4 V. So, with the potentiometer wiper at the low voltage end of the potentiometer, the voltage will be almost exactly what is needed for negligible output current of LM312. (That negligible output current will flow through the potentiometer and also through the adjust pin of the voltage controlling LM312 leaving the final output current at 0.
